# DataFrame merge on keys which are NOT equal

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I got table A:

```
 A = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,5],
                       'b':['II','I','I','III','II'],
                       'c':['I', 'II', 'II', 'III', 'II'],
                       'd':[0,2,0,2,0],
                       'e':[0,2,0,3,0],
                       'f':[0,3,0,4,0],})
```

**To be short,** i want to write this SQL code in pandas:

```
proc sql;
    create table MERGED as
    select distinct T1.*,
    T2.a as a_merged
    from A as T1
    left join A as T2
    on T1.b = T2.b and T1.c = T2.c and 
    T2.d = 0 and T2.e = 0 and T1.f ^= T2.f;
run;
```

**Problem is:** I dont know(I can't find), how to implement 3, 4 and **last** condition with `pd.merge`.
The first two are simple....:

```
MERGED = A.merge(A, how = 'left', on = ['b', 'c'] ,suffixes=('', '_r'))
```

**So the result should be:**

```
B = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,5],
                       'b':['II','I','I','III','II'],
                       'c':['II', 'II', 'II', 'III', 'II'],
                       'd':[1,2,0,2,0],
                       'e':[0,2,0,3,0],
                       'f':[0,3,0,4,0],
                 'a_r':['',2,'','','']})
```

Comment: Looks to me the first two are not part of the merge, but here you are filtering.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Sorry? The first two are the MAIN part of the merge

Comment: @LandenkovVladislav: `T2.d = 0 and T2.e = 0` is part of the merge? You could do those independently from the merge. Usually SQL will first filter `T2` before it merges, since it reduces computation cost.

Comment: Generally, you are right. I didnt understand what were you talking about. BUT in my case, i want to keep it in merge, since it containce a logic, which is easy to understand in `merge` without separating. Also, what about the 3rd?

Comment: @LandenkovVladislav: the third one can indeed be a join operator (although I wonder whether that is supported in pandas).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Why did you delete the answer. I'm using you solution eventually